# R ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1661, 3)

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

Here is my code:

```
used_time_period = "2009-01-01::2017-04-01"

data_used = data_input[used_time_period,]

split_coefficient = 0.8

train_set_rate = round(nrow(data_used) * split_coefficient)

data_train = data_used[1:train_set_rate,]

data_test = data_used[(train_set_rate + 1):nrow(data_used),]

model = keras_model_sequential() %>%

layer_simple_rnn(units = 75, input_shape = dim(data_train[,1:3]), activation = "relu", return_sequences = TRUE) %>% 
layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "relu")

model %>% compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics = "binary_accuracy")

history = model %>% fit(x = data_train[,1:3], y = data_train[,4:5], epochs = 40, batch_size = 20)
```

the error i'm getting is this:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_input to
>   have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1661, 3)
>
> dim(data_train[,1:3]) = (1661, 3)
>
> dim(data_train[,4:5]) = (1661, 2)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `layer_simple_rnn` requires a 3D array but you are using a `data.frame`, which is a 2D array (a table with rows and columns).

According to the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#rnn), the recurrent layer needs an array with shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. Assuming each column corresponds to a different date (correct me if I'm wrong), this should probably work:

```
dim(data_train[, 1:3]) # [1] 10  3
X <- as.matrix(data_train[, 1:3]) # Convert to an array
dim(X) # [1] 10  3

dim(X) <- c(dim(X), 1)
dim(X) # [1] 10  3  1

# The same for Y
Y <- as.matrix(data_train[, 4:5])
dim(Y) <- c(dim(Y), 1)
```

Now `X` and `Y` have 3 dimensions and you can feed them to your model:

```
history = model %>% fit(x = X, y = Y, epochs = 40, batch_size = 20)
```

Comment: When I apply these changes I get:  ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_25_input to have shape (1661, 3) but got array with shape (3, 1)
But when I use:
`dim(X) <- c(1, dim(X))`
`dim(Y) <- c(1, dim(Y))`
Everything works! Thanks a lot!